# Latex formatting on iMessage?

Tags: messages, latex

I was wondering,

is it possible to allow for simple latex formatting on iMessage?
At least for just greek letters, it shouldn't be too different from the emoticons support.

Comment: It is very different from emoticon support. Emoticons are just letters (as greek letters). LaTeX needs an piece of code interpreting it and rendering the output.

Comment: Of course, I see what you mean. This is why I was asking for SIMPLE latex support, meaning just single symbols.

Answer (score 4):

It is actually possible to send arbitrarily complex LaTeX formulae with the help of [LaTeXiT](http://pierre.chachatelier.fr/latexit/latexit-home.php?lang=en). The trick is fairly simple:

1. Enter the LaTeXiT preferences and, in the first tab, set the export
   format as `PNG`. I also suggest to set the Scale to 250%, but this is a matter of taste.
2. Type a LaTeX formula in iMessage (not need to put the dollars)
3. Highlight the text, go to the `iMessage -> Services` menu and choose any of the LaTeXiT services (for instance, the "Display" one)
4. **Ta-dah!** After few seconds, your Tex code will be converted into a PNG image, ready to be sent through iMessage!

PS: In case you don't see the service in the menu, go to your system preference and activate it:

[image]

Comment: Cool! It would now be interesting to find a way to automatically convert to an image any time you write something enclosed in two dollar signs, although another (dirty) way is simply to call one of those services through a keyboard shortcut and/or a BetterTouchTool gesture

Answer (score 1):

The Emoticons you are talking about are Emojis.

The emojis are part of the Unicode set. Apple provides a keyboard for this set of unicode characters.

What you need is a keyboard that provides the unicode characters you want.
Maybe just adding a greek keyboard in the system settings could solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

A dirty solution: use LaTeXiT (http://pierre.chachatelier.fr/latexit/latexit-home.php?lang=en), simply type whatever you need to write into iMessage there, then copy the result as an image and paste it into iMessage.

[image]

Comment: Dirty but rather useful!

Comment: There should actually be a "service" (Appname Menu->Services->...) which *should* let you TeXify anything that you write, but I never figured out how this works, if you ever manage, let me know ;-)
http://cl.ly/image/462t16273Y1r/Image%202015-02-09%20at%207.01.06%20PM.png

Comment: Actually I did! I will now post what I found :-)